# CORS issue with apache2 serving vite

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, apache2, vite

I am trying to host an apache2 web server that redirects all traffic goint to '/tov' to a vite server running on port 8080. I am hoping this is a simple fix on the apache side as I am very unfamaliar with it.

apache2 config:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName exmaple.org
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ProxyRequests on
  ProxyPass /tov http://localhost:8080
  ProxyPassReverse /tov http://localhost:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

This should redirect everything going to http://example.com/tov to port 8080

Here is my vite.config

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 8080,
  }
})
```

This successfully serves the vite app on port 8080. It is reachable via example.com:8080, but I want to to be reachable by example.com/tov

When pointing firefox to http://example.com/tov, I get:

```
An error occurred during a connection to www.example.com. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
```

This is strange. I am not doing anything with SSL. A few minutes ago, the page was loading and I was getting a MIME type error for text/html in the console. This may be an issue with firefox.

When pointing chrome to http://example.com/tov, I get

```
GET http://www.example.com/@vite/client net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tov:6          GET http://example.com/@react-refresh net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tov:20          GET http://example.com/src/main.tsx net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
favicon.svg:1          GET http://example.com/src/favicon.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

Any ideas? I could be going about this the wrong way.

Comment: `SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.` ... doesn't look like a CORS issue

Comment: `This may be an issue with firefox` - no, it's an issue with the server sending the incorrect mime type for the content ... e.g. `text/html` when fetching javascript will be an issue in all browsers - but some may be forgiving